# I want to upload an image to folder using javascript and generic handler in c#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, handler, httpcontext

```
    function ajaxFileUpload(mode) {
    var fupl = 'fileToUpload';
    var fileName = $('#fileuploadbrand').val();
    if (fileName == "" || fileName == null)//if user doesn't select an image
    {
        alert('Please Select An image');
    }
    else {
        var vars = fileName.split("."); //get file extension.
        if (vars[1].toString().toLowerCase() != "jpg")
        {//check the file extension.
            alert('The image format is not valid !');
          
            return false;
        }
      
       
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../handlers/BandPictureHandler.ashx',
            data: { Action: mode },
            cache: false,
            fileElementId: 'fileToUpload',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.result == "successed")
                    alert('Image Uploaded');
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("error");
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

> This is my javascript code. Where Using debugging I can see that file
> is coming and it also hits the handler. But In the handler, It is not going to the "new" case. It always redirect to the default case. Below I am giving the handler code. Please help to to store the image in folder using javascript. If there is any easy step,then you can also suggest it to me.

public class BandPictureHandler : IHttpHandler {

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpRequest request = context.Request;
    HttpResponse response = context.Response;
    string action = request["Action"];
    switch (action)
    {
        case "NEW":
            string result = "failed";
            try
            {
                string fileName = SaveCaper(context);
                result = "successed";
                response.Write("{\"result\":" + result.ToString().ToLower() + "}");
            }
            catch
            {
                response.Write("{\"result\":" + result.ToString().ToLower() + "}");
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

private string SaveCaper(HttpContext context)
{
    string fileName = string.Empty;
    string path = context.Server.MapPath("~/assets/media/brand/");
    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    try
    {
        var file = context.Request.Files[0];
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Browser.ToUpper() == "IE")
        {
            string[] files = file.FileName.Split(new char[] { '\\' });
            fileName = files[files.Length - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            fileName = file.FileName;
        }
        string strFileName = fileName;
        fileName = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
        try
        {
            file.SaveAs(fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            //log the exception
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        //log the exception
    }
    return fileName;
}
public bool IsReusable {
    get {
        return false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you looked in your browser's Network tool and examine the request, and checked what value is being sent for the "Action" field?

Comment: No in action feild, I am getting null

Comment: On the server-side, or the client-side? If it's null on the client-side you need to trace back to the code which is executing the ajaxFileUpload() function and see what value it passes for the `mode` parameter.

Comment: No I am getting on handler only and it is on server site

Comment: Could you please help me?

Comment: " it is on server site "... Like I said in my very first comment, you need to debug the client-side code too. Use your browser's Developer Tools to do so.